# Parsing query parameters which has ampersand in its values

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

We are trying to parse query parameters for the below URL

https://example.com?a=a1&b=b1&cd=C&D&ef=E&F

We want the parameters to read as

```
a = a1
b = b1
cd = C&D
ef = E&F
```

Currently, we are using the below javascript

```
var url_string = "https://example.com?a=a1&b=b1&cd=C&D&ef=E&F"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var cd = url.searchParams.get("cd");
console.log(cd);
```

It reads the value of `cd` as `C` and not `C&D`
The issue is because the URL has an ampersand in the query parameter values. 
How can I get the full value i.e. `C&D` for the query parameter `cd` ?

Comment: You should use URL encoded value `%26` for the value of the query parameter `cd` at the first place.

Comment: @fiveelements - URL is from an external system and we are not constructing it

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to follow standard URLs; i.e. URL encode ? and &'s.

```js
// & -> %26
// ? -> %3F
let urlStr = 'https://example.com?a=a%26b%3Fc';
let url = new URL(urlStr);
console.log(url.searchParams.get('a')); // a&b?c
```

Alternatively, if you **must** use **incorrect** URLs, then you'll have to resort to your own custom parser. Standard URL parsers will assume correctly formatted URLs. The problem with this approach of using incorrect URLs is you have no way to know for certain whether `?a=x&b` means

1) the param `a` has value `'x&b'`, or

2) the param `a` has value `'x'` and the param `b` has value `''` (empty string). I.e., `example.com/?b` actually means something different than `example.com`, in the first case, param `b` has value empty string, in the 2nd there is no param `b`.

Comment: We are getting this URL from an external system and we are getting incorrect URL. So we have to read the query parameters in some way

Comment: Why do you assume the URL is incorrect (i.e. `?a=b&c` means param `a` has value `'b&c'`) rather than correct (i.e. `?a=b&c` means param `a` has value `'b'` while param `c` has value `''`).